# Javascript coding help. Skipping a certain part of code

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to code a web application and I have encountered a slight issue.
In the top part of the code there is a moving item around the screen. I called that item to randomly move around the screen in the beginning of my code. But then when I click a button its suppose to stop. So what I did was I created a function for when it's clicked, and it captures the x,y,z into a local variable in the function. I then entered these fixed x,y,z values into the item so it remains stationary, but for some reason I think its being overwritten by the top code and still keeps on moving. Is there any way to skip a line of code in the top section of a code when a specific function is made to run?

Code I'm talking about

```
function motionUpdate()
{
  xvalues= //huge code which is obtained from device sensors
  yvalues= //huge code which is obtained from device sensors
  zvalues= //huge code which is obtained from device sensors

  //There are two objects that move id1 and id2. When clicking on button id2 should stop
  ui.elememenTranslate(xvalues,yvalues,zvalues,"id1") //moves according to x,y,z location
  ui.elememenTranslate(xvalues,yvalues,zvalues,"id2")
}
self.Click = function()
{
  var localX = xvalues;
  var localY = yvalues;
  var localZ = yvalues;
  ui.elememenTranslate(xvalues,yvalues,zvalues,"id2")
}
```

Comment: Questions about code pretty much ALWAYS need to include the actual code you're asking about.  We can't guess what you're doing from just the words.

Comment: firstly you need to share your code and secondly, a flag can help you to decide if a certain section of code you want to execute or not.

Comment: I added the code. hope you understand me now :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a global variable as a condition for the code to run. Example:

```
var run_code = true;
```

Then in the code:

```
function motionUpdate()
{
    if(run_code) // if run_code is true, else skip this part
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

In other part of code under certain condition, set as required:

```
run_code = false;
```

Once set, above code will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Ashad Shanto's comment, you can use a flag to save if the button has been clicked.

```
// Save if the button was clicked
var id2IsStopped = false;

function motionUpdate(){
     ...
    ui.elememenTranslate(xvalues,yvalues,zvalues,"id1") //moves according to x,y,z location

    // Don't run translate if the button was clicked
    if(!id2IsStopped){
        ui.elememenTranslate(xvalues,yvalues,zvalues,"id2")
    }
}

self.Click = function(){
    ...
    ui.elememenTranslate(xvalues,yvalues,zvalues,"id2");

    // Record that the button was clicked
    id2IsStopped = true;
}
```

This will record the clicked button and stop running the translation on id2.  However, if you want to toggle id2's movement, you just need to toggle the value of the flag:

```
// Previously: id2IsStopped = true;
id2IsStopped = !id2IsStopped;
```